# Why's initializing a global variable with return value of a function failing at declaration,but works fine at file scope?

Tags: c, initialization, global-variables, constants

An `80k` reputation contributor **R..** told me on SO that we can't initialize global variables with the return value of a function as that's not considered a constant,and global variables must be initialized with a constant.And true to his words,I get the following error for this program as expected-- `initializer element is not a constant`.Here is the program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int foo();
int gvar=foo();  //ERROR

int main()
{
printf("%d",gvar);
}

int foo()
{
 return 8;
}
```

But in this context,I just don't understand why the followed altered version of the above program shows no error at all and works fine.In this second program,I am initializing the same global variable with the return value of the **same** function `foo()`.Can you tell me what is the rigorous technical reason for this variation in results?Why is initializing the global variable with the return value of a function at it's declaration causing error but the same initialization with the same return value works fine when done from within a function?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int foo();
int gvar;

int main()
{
gvar=foo();
printf("%d",gvar);
}

int foo()
{
return 8;
}
```

**Output**     `8`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason behind it is that in order to determine a value produced by a function one needs to execute code, and that there is no code execution done in C when initializing static and global variables.

Compiler and linker work together to prepare a byte image of the global memory segment: the compiler provides the values, and the linker performs their final layout. At runtime, the image of the segment is loaded in memory as is, without further modifications. This happens before any code gets executed, so no function calls can be made.

Note that this does not mean that it is not possible for some technical reason, only that C designers decided against doing it. For example, C++ compiler generates a code segment that calls constructors of global objects, which gets executed before the control is passed to main().

Comment: +1 for C++. I was not sure how C++ compiler/linker manages to do that. So it seems, that assigning function result to global variable in C++ is the same as doing second question's program but it is just hidden from the source code? Essentially a built-in macro?

Answer (score 6):

The second version doesn't have an initializer for `gvar`. `gvar` is declared and defined at global scope without an initializer. It has static storage duration, so it is initialized with zero.

The assignment in `main` is just that: an assignment, not an initialization.

Answer (score 1):

In case 1, global variable is assigned with a variable while it is **declared**.

But in the second case, global variable is assigned(**which is already declared**) with return value of foo().

Forming of data section, text section all happens during compilation.

Global variables will be in data section(bss or initialized data section), so at compile time, foo() is not invoked right? and return value of foo() is not known during compilation.

But second case, when the text section get executed, `gvar` is assigned with return value of foo(). It is valid.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe think of it like this: when `main()` starts, all global variables must already have their initializer values. And they can't, as you've been told, get those by calling functions since `main()` is really where execution starts, in a C program.

Answer (score 1):

In C, generally, we cannot call a function at global scope. It is not like shell scripts. Functions are only allowed to be called from inside the body of other functions, with execution beginning from `main()` function. Otherwise, at global scope, we come across function prototypes, with parameters and return type specified.

We can assign to any variable, the return value of a function by calling it from `main` or from other functions. The function called then modifies that variable (which could be a global variable).

At the same time, we can use a macro in a global variable declaration (and initialization) as follows,
as:

```
#define max() 12 
int glob=max();

main()
{

}
```