# Conditional Operator the only way to initialize global variables at a global scope?

Tags: c++, initialization

Ok so I have a header file full of global variables.
here's an example how the implementation looks like (in the .cpp file):

```
extern double event::m_chance = 0.01;
```

Nothing special so far. But when my code became more complex, I started to implement a `#define MASTER_MODE` for testing purposes.
So now it looks like this:

```
extern double event::m_chance = MASTER_MODE ? 0.5 : 0.01;
```

and I asked myself: is this the *only* way to initialize global variables at a global scope (with a condition)? 
since an if-statement does not work here... It must be, right?

```
//declarations
extern double event::m_chance;

if (MASTER_MODE) { //Error: excepted a declaration
    event::m_chance = 0.5;
    //other variables should be here
}
else { //nope
    event::m_chance = 0.01;
    //other variables should be here
}
```

I just ask myself if this is what everyone else does at my position. Or is there a *nicer* (*standard*-defined) way to init them.. (like making an extra function etc).

Thanks for your help / advices!

Comment: I would do the same thing as you do in your first example. But if you want to change the variable or change the structure of your code you can always assign the default value `0.01` and the do `if(MASTER_MODE) { event::m_chance = 0.5;}`. But this changes the variable during runtime not in the preprocessor

Comment: No, it is not the only way.   There are options involving template specialisation (all versions of C++) or (C++11 and later)  `constexpr` functions, lambdas, etc etc.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16354575/whys-initializing-a-global-variable-with-return-value-of-a-function-failing-at

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#ifdef MASTER_MODE

    extern double event::m_chance = 0.5;
    //other variables should be here

#else

    extern double event::m_chance = 0.01;
    //other variables should be here

#endif
```

Comment: Wow didn't even thought about that. Makes total sense and it's performance friendly! Thank you :)

Comment: @StackDanny  IMHO, performance are same than your code with ternary operator: modern compiler will always optimize condition if possible, and because condition is known at compilation time, compiler can directly put result of condition. Also, I prefer you ternary operator, because you will see directly if variable exists in both MASTER_MODE or not

Comment: But you could put the declaration *before* the #define and than it would work like an if-statement

Answer (score 0):

How about a lambda?

```
#include <iostream>

bool some_condition = true;

int some_global = [&]()
{
    if (some_condition)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else
    {
        return 20;
    }
}();

int main() {
    std::cout << some_global;
}
```

Comment: ...or result of any function/object with global linkage

Comment: this will neatly work for one variable, but I have houndreds of them!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question mentions "since an if-statement does not work here". And I was a bit naughty at that moment.